# AWS Api Gateway "put-rest-api" doesn't create trigger in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, aws-rest-api

I am trying to put template in API Gate Way with next command:

`aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id $APIGW --mode merge --body 'fileb://./api-gw-template.json'`

Template is:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "basePath" : "/aws",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/{proxy+}" : {
      "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method" : {
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "proxy",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : { },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          "httpMethod" : "POST",
          "uri" : "{{URI}}",
          "responses" : {
            "default" : {
              "statusCode" : "200"
            }
          },
          "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_match",
          "cacheNamespace" : "2wn7w2",
          "cacheKeyParameters" : [ "method.request.path.proxy" ],
          "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
          "type" : "aws_proxy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types" : [ "font/woff", "image/x-icon", "*/*" ]
}
```

This template creates a proxy resource with lambda integration, everything is fine here.
But in my lambda function, I don't see a new trigger for that resource.
But if I create the same resource manually, the trigger in the lambda is also created.
And if I export these two api gateway as swagger json template they are the same.

Also deploy api after import template doesn't help.
Here is output after import templat:

```
{
    "id": "********",
    "name": "Imported on 2022-09-14T12:09:17Z",
    "createdDate": 1663149628,
    "warnings": [
        "Required \"info\" property is missing from the document root."
    ],
    "binaryMediaTypes": [
        "font/woff",
        "image/x-icon",
        "*/*"
    ],
    "apiKeySource": "HEADER",
    "endpointConfiguration": {
        "types": [
            "REGIONAL"
        ]
    },
    "policy": "{\\\"Version\\\":\\\"2012-10-17\\\",\\\"Statement\\\":[{\\\"Effect\\\":\\\"Allow\\\",\\\"Principal\\\":\\\"*\\\",\\\"Action\\\":\\\"execute-api:Invoke\\\",\\\"Resource\\\":\\\"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:*************:***********\\/*\\/*\\/*\\\"}]}",
    "disableExecuteApiEndpoint": false
}
```

`aws apigateway put-integration` command also don't create trigger in lambda

Can someone help me? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. The lambda function needs permission to be able to be called by the API gateway integration.

Solution in my case (if you are using a resource without a proxy - specify the resource name instead of the last asterisk in the "--source-arn" key):

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name $lambda \
--statement-id apigateway-test-111111 --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:$REGION_NAME:$ACCOUNT:$APIGW/*/*/*"
```

When manually creating a resource, this permission is automatically created